# El uso de "estar" (unido con un pronombre) + gerundio

Tags: gramática

Vi varias oraciones:

"*No podemos estar**nos** planteando siempre las mismas preguntas, cada vez que se producen accidentes catastróficos*"

"*Se trata de pacientes a los que probablemente ya deberíamos estar**nos** dirigiendo como candidatos para modificación agresiva del riesgo*"

"*El deseo de coherencia e integración puede estar**nos** inmovilizando del todo*"

Antes pensaba que el pronombre en este caso (porque entiendo que hay otros casos en los que entiendo la gramática - "*debería haberte escrito*") solo se podría usar antes de toda da estructura (que consiste de varios verbos) o junto con el gerundio. Es decir, que solo se puede escribir así:

1. *No podemos estar planteándo**nos** siempre las mismas preguntas, cada vez que se producen accidentes catastróficos / No **nos** podemos estar planteando siempre las mismas preguntas, cada vez que se producen accidentes catastróficos.*
2. *Se trata de pacientes a los que probablemente ya deberíamos estar dirigiéndo**nos** como candidatos para modificación agresiva del riesgo / Se trata de pacientes a los que probablemente ya **nos** deberíamos estar dirigiendo como candidatos para modificación agresiva del riesgo*
3. *El deseo de coherencia e integración puede estar inmovilizándo**nos** del todo / El deseo de coherencia e integración **nos** puede estar inmovilizando del todo*

Entonces, por qué es posible usar "estar" junto con un pronombre así?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es una situación muy fina, ya que, en primer lugar, todos tus ejemplos son de perífrasis verbales. O incluso se podría pensar como perífrasis anidadas si la palabra en gerundio la tomamos como verbo y no como adverbio. Sea como fuere, difícilmente pueda encontrarse algún libro que dé un tratamiento tan profundo, ya que en general se mencionan reglas acerca de cuando se deben *anteponer* y cuando se deben *posponer* los enclíticos.

En este caso, el pronombre está en el medio de la perífrasis así que no es ni anteposición, ni posposición. Al consultar fuentes, lo más cercano que encontré fue:

> **Cuando hay encadenamiento de perífrasis, las opciones
> de colocación son mayores**. De este modo, resultan
> igualmente válidas:
>
> 'No voy a poder leer**lo**';
>
> 'No voy a poder**lo** leer';
>
> 'No **lo** voy a poder leer'.
>
> [RAE, ASALE, *El buen uso del español*, *Uso y posición de los pronombres átonos
> (I)*]

> d) Los clíticos se posponen a las formas simples de infinitivo y de gerundio: 'Al mirarlo, sonrió'; 'No conseguirás nada regañándome'. Pero, **si el infinitivo o el gerundio forman parte de una perífrasis verbal, o el infinitivo se subordina a otros verbos, se observa cierta libertad en la colocación de los clíticos, que, en la mayor parte de los casos, pueden combinarse con cualquiera de los verbos de la serie**: 'Debo hacerlo / Lo debo hacer'; 'Me da pereza tener que llevársela / Me da pereza tenérsela que llevar'; 'Vais a arrepentiros / Os vais a arrepentir'; 'Siempre está quejándose / Siempre se está quejando'; 'Siguió explicándomelo / Me lo siguió explicando'; 'Pensaba acabar de contároslo hoy / Pensaba acabároslo de contar hoy / Os lo pensaba acabar de contar hoy'. **En los registros más formales se suele preferir situar los clíticos tras el último verbo** (es decir, la primera de las opciones consignadas en cada ejemplo). [[Diccionario panhispánico de dudas](https://www.rae.es/dpd/pronombres%20personales%20%C3%A1tonos)]

Como ves, no están muy especificados los límites de esta 'libertad'. Pero aún queda otra diferencia por analizar. ¿Se puede usar el enclítico con un verbo copulativo, en este caso 'estar'? Creo que es esto más polémico que aquello en lo que respecta a la posición del enclítico *per se*. Bajo mi punto de vista no veo razón para prohibirlo, pero tampoco he encontrado ejemplos en ningún libro ni en ningún sitio en donde esto suceda.

De momento, mi conclusión es: si es para un examen, definitivamente eligiría los estilos de los ejemplos que mencionás en el segundo caso porque es seguro que están aceptados y no te lo pueden discutir. En la práctica, sobre todo en lenguaje coloquial, suelo escuchar cualquiera de los estilos que mostrás en tus ejemplos; por lo que dudo mucho que en una conversación con nativos alguien te reproche por hablar como en las primeras tres oraciones.